# Google+ share API

Tags: python, google-api, google-plus

I have found Facebook and Twitter APIs for their "share" information on the website, but I can't seem to find the [Google+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google%2B) API. How do I get the Google+ share count from a URL using Python?